# Overwriting an element.style attribute for an image

Tags: html, css, styles

I  am using this `<div class="wk_seller_store_logo" data-productid ="{{product.id}}"></div>`

to insert an image linking back to a profile and I believe the element.style is controlling the image size at 50px as I can change it in the inspector but cannot figure out how to overwrite either the java script or CSS. Is it a simple overwrite i can add to the html? `max-height 250px !important`
or something like this?

Thanks guys, totally new here!

Comment: Please show us some more code. Or CSS file. Do you if you edit you main css file  or js file ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask a good question and update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have the information we need to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks always helping I managed with the solution provided below ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the image is rendered in the div which you gave above `<div class="wk_seller_store_logo" data-productid ="{{product.id}}"></div>` , then you can simply add the following rules in your CSS file to override the `image` element styling:

```
.wk_seller_store_logo img{
    width:250px !important;
    height:250px !important;
}
```

If you want to change it using js then please share the js code which is adding the element style to image.

Comment: I would not recommend to add `!important` since it will override all the properties for the element, this has to be considered as a last option. I suggest OP to look into inspect elements and act accordingly.

Comment: Yes you are right, but only way to override an inline css `style` rule is to use !important

Comment: perfect! I added this to the css '.wk_seller_store_logo img{
    width:250px !important;
    height:250px !important;
   max-height:250px !important
}'

Comment: I see that each element is using the !important, with just width and height without max height it skewed the image

Comment: Great, glad to know it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS, you can use .dataset to retrieve the information of what logo comong from your data tag and .style to change the width... Below is an example of how it could be achieved...

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('wk_seller_store_logo');
let logo = {'wk_seller_store': 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTx3obz2G2UBHkVd-x1eTlEc_QdopClZKmeP72T1f5a5tFPqXeF&usqp=CAU'}; //<-- to illustrate getting the image from an array or object
let data = document.getElementsByClassName('wk_seller_store_logo'); //<-- Get the element that holds the dataset productid
let image = document.getElementsByClassName('image'); //<-- img tag to illustrate placing logo/img and styling logo/img
let productID = data[0].dataset['productid'];//<-- get the img source from the array or object using the dataset key value
image[0].src = logo[productID];//<-- set the value of the src attribute within the img tag to the value of the productid's key from the array 'logo' which is the `dataset['productid']` from your element
image[0].style.width = '200px';// style the image to be 200px wide `element.style`
```

```html
<div class="wk_seller_store_logo" data-productid="wk_seller_store"></div>
<img class="image" src='' />
```

Comment: This is also very useful, thank you!